# Can you ask questions about using an interface builder?

Tags: discussion

I was wondering there should be questions that state something along the lines of this(I have been guilty of this):

> Is there a way to do this in X interface builder?

These don't really seem to have to do with programming per se. I understand that many iOS issues involve the interface builder, but there are questions where the asker only really cares for an interface builder solution and not a programmatic one.

Are these really on topic? Is there another site where this sort of question would be better suited?

This might also apply to other development scenarios (like Android), but I haven't been active enough with those types of questions to know.

Comment: I've tried to make the question a bit easier to read -- if I've misunderstood what you wanted to ask, please change it back. BTW it's particularly bad with iOS and Xcode, there have been a few discussions about that one in particular.

Comment: Perfectly fine :)

Comment: Yes,  Of course.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It sure is on topic - we allow questions about [software tools and their usage](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

[image]

Do make sure you follow the normal question guidelines though - make sure you illustrate what you've tried and what you intend to do, and if possible what's not working.

Comment: But what about people who ask solely about an interface builder solution. Also I saw that excel scripting is on topic, but would general excel questions be allowed?

Comment: @cabellicar123 General Excel questions would be migrated to [Super User](http://superuser.com/). General interface builder questions are fine, but if the interface builder was solely a drag-drop WYSIWYG type with no coding required then that might also become a candidate for Super User.

Comment: When you say candidate do you mean should be migrated there or are they better here?

Comment: If they fit the definition then they are better there to begin with, if they are posted on Stack Overflow then they will usually get migrated (sometimes they'll just get closed without migration).

Comment: Ok. Thanks for helping to clear this up for me! Cheers!

Comment: That arrow is far too straight and lacks the hand-drawn effect that SO style demands.  Please see that it is updated.

Comment: @slugster Hm. With this view, any "programming" what is done _purely_ by WYSIWYG is not allowed? One example for many: `OS X Automator programs`. Automator is Drag&Drop but the order of actions and the logic of a created "application" (e.g. how to using variables (with drag&drop too)) is a (sort of) programming. Or I need to change my mental model, what is mean "programming"? IMHO, the philosophy: _This is pure WYSIWYG, so should be migrated_ not the best. To interface builder: I can't imagine why someone using IB if not for programming task. So, IB questions should be allowed fully.

Comment: @jm: Whether you call wiring up an interface programming or not, fact is that questions about e.g. LabView VIs don't fit well in StackOverflow.  It's very hard to post the code when there is no code.  And no, screenshots of the interactive wiring tool are not sufficient in any except the most trivial SSCCE.

Comment: @BenVoigt: so basically are you saying that the inability to provide a test case in Unicode text prevents asking a good question about that kind of programming? That's kind of the same issue that prompts people to request fiddles of JS questions: the test case is otherwise considered inadequate since it's significant effort to set up (save several files). In the case of LabView, using it to view a binary is critically much effort, I suppose, and furthermore SO doesn't provide a neat way to attach the SSCCE to a question.

Comment: @paqogomez Done :)

Comment: @SteveJessop: I didn't say it prevents asking a good question.  I said it prevents doing so *on the StackExchange engine*.  Questions can contain Javascript code; they can't contain hierarchical diagrams.